# How can I make something when I click my chart?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, charts

I would like to make an onClick event that when I click on a bar it makes a console log, how can I do it?

```
state = {
    chartData: {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Covid-19',
          data: [],
          backgroundColor:'red',
          borderColor: 'red',
          hoverBackgroundColor: 'green',
          hoverBorderColor: 'green',
          borderWidth: 4,
          responsive: true,
        }
      ],
    }
  }



<div className="container">
    <Bar  data={this.state.chartData}}/>
  </div>
```

[image: This is my chart built with react-chartjs-2]

Comment: You'll have to show us the implementation of `Bar`. You can only assign an `onClick` handler to a dom element. So you'll just need to pass the handler down to something that eventually becomes a dom element

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

please try like as below snippet code.

```
onClick = (e) => {
   var data = e.target.data;
   console.log(data);
}

...
state = {
    chartData: {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Covid-19',
          data: [],
          backgroundColor:'red',
          borderColor: 'red',
          hoverBackgroundColor: 'green',
          hoverBorderColor: 'green',
          borderWidth: 4,
          responsive: true,
        }
      ],
    }
  }



<div className="container">
    <Bar  onClick={(e)=>this.onClick()} data={this.state.chartData}}/>
  </div>
```